# Can my husband perform oral sex?

Tags: halal-haram, sex

My husband wants to kiss my vagina and suck it so I let him, and I love it when he does, that but I saw that it was haram.

Another problem is that I have one child who is 1 years old.  One day me and my husband were having sex and he woke up (he sleeps with us), so what should I do when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Kissing of woman's vagina is not haram , but it is makrooh (disliked) and is no a sin if you do it. but he has to do it with care, means the vaginal fluids should never go inside his mouth, if he is careful till that level, its fine

About the Child waking up, there is no hard and fast rule in Islam that what to do in that situation. you can try to keep him calm and make him sleep and get busy with husband again.

And Allah knows the best.

Here is fatwa about licking or sucking woman private part: http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/1483